# IE js error with event.target !==

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following js code:

```
if ( event.target !== self.element[ 0 ]){
  ...
 }
```

In IE browser I get this error:
Object doesn't support this property or method

when I write my code :

```
if ( event.target == self.element[ 0 ]){
  ...
 }
```

I don't get a js problem

what is not supported by IE? the !==?!!

Comment: Out of curiosity if nothing else, what does `===` result in?

Comment: Clear the cache and try again

Comment: The issue may be within the `...` rather than the condition. Between the 2 snippets, they may not both execute the block.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it appears that @nannou is using `...` (an ellipsis) as a placeholder for the code.

Comment: @jsve Sorry. Yeah. I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. Just meant that the code represented by `...` may also be contributing to the "*fine in one, error in the other*."

Answer (score 4):

Well there's no "target" property in IE; it's `event.srcElement`.  So try

```
if ((event.target || event.srcElement) !== self.element[0])
```

Comment: You are right, just one more information, on IE you need to access event objet with window.event, so you must define this before : `code` evt = evt || window.event;

Comment: @radia yes, that too!